# Ios: Set sub class as delegate for super class ->superclass delegates blocked for other classes

Tags: objective-c, delegates, subclass

I have a sub class UIUnitTextField of a UITextField which handles the input of the TextField itself (Value in range check, isNumeric and some other things)
For this, I did set the sub class as delegate for the UITextField `[self setDelegate:self]`, so the input can be validated in the `(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UIUnitTextField *)textField` method in my sub class.

This all works wonderful, with one catch. The delegate for the UITextField is now already set. As I wanted to implement a solution against the keyboard hiding a TextField, I need to use the `(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UIUnitTextField *)textField` again in the controller view. This is of course not possible.

This leads me to the thought, that I did not good, with using the delegate of the UITextField class for the sub class UIUnitTextField, but I cannot think about another way to handle the input like this.
Did anyone already had this problem? What could be a way to solve this conflict?

I'm thankful for any good input or mind push.

**update- I had a new thought**
Would it be okay, if I overwrite the `setDelegate` method in the sub class like this, and just forward the call to the subDelegate?

```
//set own delegate
-(void)didMoveToSuperview{
   super.delegate = self;

//set numeric keayboard type with a custome "done" button
[self setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad];
NumberPadDoneBtn* nmbPad=[[NumberPadDoneBtn alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,1,1)];
[self setInputAccessoryView:nmbPad];

}
-(void)setDelegate:(id<UIUnitTextFieldDelegate>)delegate{
    [self setSubDelegate:delegate];
}

//before editing, remove unit string from text
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UIUnitTextField *)textField{
    super.text = [self removeUnit:super.text];
    [self.subDelegate textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UIUnitTextField *)textField];
}
```

Comment: Making an object its own delegate usually doesn't work well. Instead, it's usually best to hook into the machinery that sends delegate messages. In this case, that might be `UITextFieldDidEndEditingNotification`.

Comment: @rickster That's exactly what I've been searching :) Thank you. I'll post an answer with the example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rickster gave me the tip to use `UITextFieldTextDidEndEditingNotification`. This is exactly what I've ben looking for. The implementation was surprisingly easy

```
-(void)didMoveToSuperview{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(textFieldDidEndEditingNotification)
                                                 name:UITextFieldTextDidEndEditingNotification
                                               object:self];
}
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditingNotification{
//do stuff
}
```